# How to find out which compile steps are necessary?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, mactex

I have been using LaTeX for quite a while now, but I have not found out how to determine the rules for the compilation steps needed to create the document yet.

A couple of questions come up. Please do not hesitate to provide a really short answer, I just do not know where to start.

`texify` belongs to MikTeX and runs `pdflatex` plus what else is needed. What is the equivalent for MacTeX?

When I would like to launch a recompilation script, it would probably make sense to run `texify` only once so that I do not have to take care of running BibTeX, pdflatex and others multiple times. Is that correct?

What would be the best approach to write a simple script that compiles everything that is needed in the correct order?

There is a grunt plugin that compiles latex, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tvooo/grunt-latex), I do not understand how a simple `pdflatex` call could correctly compile everything. Is that possible?